# Get Line number of Text.RegularExpressions.Regex matches

Tags: regex, powershell, logging, regex-group

I use PowerShell to parse a directory of Log files and extract all XML entries out of the log files. This works pretty ok. However since a log file can contain many of these xml bits and pieces I want to put the line number of the specific match it found it in also in the filename of the XML file I write, So I can open the log file and jump to that specific line to do some root cause analysis.

There is a field "index" which is i think the character count, this probably should lead me to the line number, I think however the "index" somehow includes something else as Measure-Object -Character since the value of Index is greater than the size found with Measure-Object-Character e.g. $m.groups[0].Captures[0].Index is 9963166 but Measure-Object -Character overall files in the log dir give 9838833 as max, so I think it counts newlines also.

So the question is probably:
If matches delivers me "index" as property, how do I know how many newlines that "index" contains? Do I have to get "index" characters from the file, then check how many newlines it contains and THEN I have the line? Probably.

```
$tag = 'data_json'
$input_dir = $absolute_root_dir + $specific_dir
$output_dir = $input_dir  + 'ParsedDataFiles\'
$OFS = "`r`n"
$nice_specific_dir = $specific_dir.Replace('\','_')
$nice_specific_dir = $nice_specific_dir.Replace(':','_')
$regex = New-Object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex "<$tag>(.+?)<\/$tag>", ('singleline', 'multiline')
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $output_dir
Get-ChildItem -Path $input_dir -Name -File | % {   
    $output_file = $output_dir + $nice_specific_dir + $_ + '.'
    $content = Get-Content ($input_dir + $_)
    $i = 0
    foreach($m in $regex.Matches($content)) {        
        $outputfile_xml = $output_file + $i++ + '.xml'
        $outputfile_txt = $output_file + $i++ + '.txt'
        $xml = [xml] ("<" + $tag+ ">" + $m.Groups[1].Value + "</" + $tag + ">")
        $xml.Save($outputfile_xml)
        $j = 0
        $xml.data_json.Messages.source.item | % { $_.SortOrder + ", " + $_.StartOn + ", " + $_.EndOn + ", " + $_.Id } | sort | %  { 
            (($j++).ToString() + ", " + $_ )   | Out-File $outputfile_txt -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Note: If what your regular expression matches is guaranteed to never span multiple lines, i.e. if the matched text is guaranteed to be on a *single line*, consider a simpler `Select-String`-based solution as shown in [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829072/45375); generally, though, a method/expression-based solution, as in this answer, will perform better.</sup>

---

Your first problem is that you use `Get-Content` without `-Raw`, which reads the input file as an *array of lines* rather than a single, multi-line string.

When you pass this array to `$regex.Matches()`, PowerShell stringifies the array by joining the element *with spaces* (by default).

Therefore, **read your input file with `Get-Content -Raw`**, which **ensures that it is read as single, multi-line string with newlines intact**:

```
# Read entire file as single string
$content = Get-Content -Raw ($input_dir + $_)
```

---

Once you match against a multi-line string, **you can infer the line number by counting the number of lines in the substring up to the character index at which each match was found, via `.Substring()` and `Measure-Object -Line`**:

Here's a simplified, self-contained example (see the bottom section if you also want to determine the *column* number):

```
# Sample multi-line input.
# Note: The <title> elements are at lines 3 and 6, respectively.
$content = @'
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <title>De Profundis</title>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
    <title>Pygmalion</title>
  </book>
</catalog>
'@

# Regex that finds all <title> elements.
# Inline option ('(?...)') 's' makes '.' match newlines too
$regex = [regex] '(?s)<title>.+?</title>'

foreach ($m in $regex.Matches($content)) {
  $lineNumber = ($content.Substring(0, $m.Index + 1) | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
  "Found '$($m.Value)' at index $($m.Index), line $lineNumber"
}
```

<sup>Note the `+ 1` in `$m.Index + 1`, which is needed to ensure that the substring doesn't *end* in a newline character, because `Measure-Object` line would disregard such a trailing newline. By including at least one additional (non-newline) character, the `<` of the matched element, the line count is always correct, even if the matched element starts at the very first column.</sup>

The above yields:

```
Found '<title>De Profundis</title>' at index 34, line 3
Found '<title>Pygmalion</title>' at index 96, line 6
```

---

In case you want to **also get the *column* number** (the `1`-based index of the character that starts the match on the line it was found):

#### Determining the line and column numbers of regex matches in multi-line strings:

```
# Sample multi-line input.
# Note: The <title> elements are at lines 3 and 6, columns 5 and 7, respectively.
$content = @'
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <title>De Profundis</title>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
      <title>Pygmalion</title>
  </book>
</catalog>
'@

# Regex that finds all <title> elements, along with the
# string that precedes them on the same line:
# Due to use of capture groups, each match $m will contain:
#  * the matched element: $m.Groups[2].Value
#  * the preceding string on the same line: $m.Groups[1].Value
# Inline options ('(?...)'):
#   * 's' makes '.' match newlines too
#   * 'm' makes '^' and '$' match the starts and ends of *individual lines*
$regex = [regex] '(?sm)(^[^\n]*)(<title>.+?</title>)'

foreach ($m in $regex.Matches($content)) {
  $lineNumber = ($content.Substring(0, $m.Index + 1) | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
  $columnNumber = 1 + $m.Groups[1].Value.Length
  "Found '$($m.Groups[2].Value)' at line $lineNumber, column $columnNumber."
}
```

The above yields:

```
Found '<title>De Profundis</title>' at line 3, column 5.
Found '<title>Pygmalion</title>' at line 6, column 7.
```

Note: For simplicity, both solutions above count the lines from the start of the string in every iteration.
In most cases this will likely still perform well enough; if not, see the variant approach in the performance benchmarks below, where the line count is calculated iteratively, with only the lines between the current and the previous match getting counted in a given iteration.

---

#### Optional reading: performance comparison of approaches to line counting:

[sln's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764608/45375) proposes using regular expressions also for *line counting*.

Comparing these approaches as well as the `.Substring()` plus `Measure-Object -Line` approach above in terms of performance may be of interest.

The following tests are based on the [`Time-Command` function](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27).

Sample result are from PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.3 on macOS 10.14.6, averaged over 100 runs; the absolute numbers will vary depending on the execution environment, but the relative ranking of the approaches (`Factor` column) seems to be the similar across platforms and PowerShell editions:

- With 1,000 lines and 1 match on the last line:

```
Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.001               # .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count iteratively…
1.07   0.001               # .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count from start…
2.22   0.002               # Repeating capture with nested newline capturing…
6.12   0.006               # Prefix capture group + Measure-Object -Line…
6.72   0.007               # Prefix capture group + newline-matching regex…
7.24   0.007               # Prefix Capture group + -split…
```

- With 20,000 lines and 20 evenly spaced matches starting at line 1,000:

```
Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.014               # .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count iteratively…
2.92   0.042               # Repeating capture with nested newline capturing…
7.50   0.107               # .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count from start…
8.39   0.119               # Prefix capture group + Measure-Object -Line…
9.50   0.135               # Prefix capture group + newline-matching regex…
9.94   0.141               # Prefix Capture group + -split…
```

Notes and conclusions:

- `Prefix capture group` refers to (variations of) "Way1" from sln's answer, whereas `Repeating capture group ...` refers to "Way2".

  - Note: For Way2, an (adaptation of) regex `(?:.*(\r?\n))*?.*?(match_me)` is used below, which is a much-improved version sln added later in a comment, whereas the version still being shown in the body of their answer (as of this writing) - `^(?:.*((?:\r?\n)?))*?(match_me)` - wouldn't work for processing *multiple* matches *in a loop*.
- The `.Substring()` + `Measure-Object -Line` approach from this answer is the fastest in all cases, but, with many matches to loop over, only if an iterative, between-matches line count is performed (`.Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count iteratively…`), whereas the solutions above use a count-lines-from-the-start-for-every-match approach for simplicity (`# .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count from start…`).
- With the Way1 approach (`Prefix capture group`), the specific method used for counting the newlines in the prefix match makes relatively little difference, though `Measure-Object -Line` is the fastest there too.

Here's the source code for the test; it's easy to experiment with match count, total number of input lines, ... by modifying the various variables near the bottom:

```bsh
# The script blocks with the various approaches.
$sbs =
  { # .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count from start
    foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches($txt, 'found')) {
      # !! Measure-Object -Line ignores a trailing \n, so if the match is at the
      # !! start of a line, we need to include at least 1 additional character for the line to register.
      $lineNo = ($txt.Substring(0, $m.Index + 1) | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
      "Found at line $lineNo (substring() + Measure-Object -Line, counted from start every time)."
    }
  },
  { # .Substring() + Measure-Object -Line, count iteratively
    $lineNo = 0; $startNdx = 0
    foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches($txt, 'found')) {
      # !! Measure-Object -Line ignores a trailing \n, so if the match is at the
      # !! start of a line, we need to include at least 1 additional character for the line to register.
      $lineNo += ($txt.Substring($startNdx, $m.Index + 1 - $startNdx) | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
      "Found at line $lineNo (substring() + Measure-Object -Line, counted iteratively)."
      $startNdx = $m.Index + $m.Value.Length
      # !! Decrement the cumulative line number to compensate for counting starting at 1 also for subsequent matches.
      --$lineNo
    }
  },
  { # Prefix capture group + Measure-Object -Line
    $lineNo = 0
    foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches($txt, '(?s)(.*?)found')) {
      # !! Measure-Object -Line ignores a trailing \n, so if the match is at the
      # !! start of a line, we need to include at least 1 additional character for the line to register.
      $lineNo += ($m.Groups[1].Value + '.' | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
      "Found at line $lineNo (prefix capture group + Substring() + Measure-Object -Line)."
      # !! Decrement the cumulative line number to compensate for counting starting at 1 also for subsequent matches.
      --$lineNo
    }
  },
  { # Prefix capture group + newline-matching regex
    $lineNo = 0
    foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches($txt, '(?s)(.*?)found')) {
      $lineNo += 1 + [regex]::Matches($m.Groups[1].Value, '\r?\n').Count
      "Found at line $lineNo (prefix capture group + newline-matching regex)."
      # !! Decrement the cumulative line number to compensate for counting starting at 1 also for subsequent matches.
      --$lineNo
    }
  },
  { # Prefix Capture group + -split
    $lineNo = 0
    foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches($txt, '(?s)(.*?)found')) {
      $lineNo += ($m.Groups[1].Value -split '\r?\n').Count
      "Found at line $lineNo (prefix capture group + -split for counting)."
      # !! Decrement the cumulative line number to compensate for counting starting at 1 also for subsequent matches.
      --$lineNo
    }
  },
  { # Repeating capture with nested newline capturing
    $lineNo = 0
    foreach ($m in [regex]::Matches($txt, '(?:.*(\r?\n))*?.*?found')) {
      $lineNo += 1 + $m.Groups[1].Captures.Count
      "Found at line $lineNo (repeating prefix capture group with newline capture)."
      # !! Decrement the cumulative line number to compensate for counting starting at 1 also for subsequent matches.
      --$lineNo
    }
  }

# Set this to 1 for debugging:
#   * runs the script blocks only once
#   * with 3 matching strings in the put.
#   * shows output so that the expected functionality (number of matches, line numbers) can be verified.
$debug = 0

$matchCount = if ($debug) { 3 } else {
  20 # Set how many matching strings should be present in the input string.
}

# Sample input:
# Create N lines that are 60 chars. wide, with the string to find on the last line...
$n = 1e3 # Set the number of lines per match.
$txt = ((1..($n-1)).foreach('ToString', '0' * 60) -join "`n") + "`n  found`n"
# ...and multiply the original string according to how many matches should be present.
$txt = $txt * $matchCount

$runsToAverage = if ($debug) { 1 } else {
  100   # Set how many test runs to report average timing for.
}
$showOutput = [bool] $debug

# Run the tests.
Time-Command -Count $runsToAverage -OutputToHost:$showOutput $sbs
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to pretend I know what you're trying to do but regex can't count. That means you'd have to do it in different ways.

**Way1**:

You could create two groups. Group 1 to match all up until what you're trying to match which is group 2. `(?s)(.*?)(match_me)`
Then when you get a match, create a string from group 1, then run a regex on it to
match line-breaks `\r?\n`. Each match from that you increment a counter, which
contains the line number of the original match_me thing.

**Way2**:

If powershell uses the Dot-Net engine =>
Match with this regex using this code ( make it powershell compatible, this is C#):

```
int line_num = 0;
var Rx = new Regex(@"^(?:.*((?:\r?\n)?))*?(match_me)");
Match M = Rx.Match(str);
if (M.Success) {
   CaptureCollection ccLineBreaks = M.Groups[1].Captures;
   line_num = ccLineBreaks.Count;
}
```

The capture collection *count* of group 1 is the amount of individual line breaks
up until the `match_me` thing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199116/discussion-on-answer-by-sln-get-line-number-of-text-regularexpressions-regex-mat).

Comment: @ mklement0 - I posted a message for you in the _chat_ as to the error with `Time-Command : The term 'Time-Command' is not recognized` I'm getting with PS 5.1 I'm not sure the chat participants are notified of new messages.

Answer (score 1):

Select-string will tell you the line number.

```
dir file | select-string two | fl
```

output

```
IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 2
Line       : two
Filename   : file
Path       : /Users/js/foo/file
Pattern    : two
Context    : 
Matches    : {0}
```

Comment: Indeed, but that won't work with _multi-line_ input, which is considered a single "line": `("one\`ntwo\`nthree" | sls two).LineNumber` yields `1`, irrespective of what string-_internal_ line the match was found on. 
While splitting the input into individual lines - `("one", "two", "three" | sls two).LineNumber` - _does_ work, note that it is only an option if the matches are guaranteed to be confined to _a single line_. With XML input (as in the question), which is frequently pretty-printed, you cannot make the assumption that an element never spans more than 1 line.

Comment: That said, +1 for showing a solution that may help future readers that _can_ assume that matches are confined to a single line, given the question's generic title.